# Why is shownModally / showingModally Event not triggered with custom Action Bar?

Tags: modal-dialog, nativescript

Currently I'm facing an issue with Nativescript-Core and binding some context-information in the "showModal"-method. I've tried the example given in the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/modal-view) and it's showing the same behavior: Whenever I'm trying to use a custom action bar in my modal (a how to is mentioned in the Nativescript-docs) the "shownModally" / "showingModally" Event is not triggered and therefore I'm not able to read out any context-information.

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something tremendously wrong?
I'd be grateful for your help! :)

Comment: I'm sure `shownModally` / `showingModally` works as I recently tested it once. Can you show some code sample how you have implemented, possibly a Playground.

Comment: I'd like to provide a playground example, but unfortunately I can't find the share function on [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/)

Comment: When you press `save`, it will give you option to Copy Url or you can directly copy from browser address bar e.g. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=FiB28v

Comment: Thanks @Narendra! I've tried the exact same thing yesterday and the last file i added to my project was always missing in the project shared through the link. Nevertheless it worked and here's the Playground: [Playground-Link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=n3FUpX)